# Call an array from property 0 in property 1 JavaScript Question

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript and came to a dead end. Version ES5.

```
var person = {
  cars: ["Ford", "Mercedes", "S Coupe"],
  garages: { 1: this.cars },
};

    console.log(person); 
//outputs 
//    {
//      cars: [ 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'S Coupe' ],
//      garages: { '1': undefined }
//    }
```

Why is garages["1"] undefined? is it because cars is not initialized?

Comment: *is it because cars is not initialized?* - The object doesn't exist yet so `this` refers to something else

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the same object to be referenced twice in `obj` you could do the following:

```js
const obj=(cars=>(
 {person:{cars,garages:{1:cars}}})
)(["Ford", "Mercedes", "S Coupe"]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition, the **this** in that aspect is seeing the global **this**.

One way to go around that is to do something like

```js
var person = {
  cars: ["Ford", "Mercedes", "S Coupe"],
  garages: { 1: person['cars'] },
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, Ahmad.

Comment: It does, I tried it on Node and It's working perfectly. I will look into the stacksnippets error.